# Jmeter Error : org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://www.google.com refused

Tags: java, jmeter

I am getting below error in browser while recording an application in Jmeter,

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://www.google.com refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ... 10 more
```

I am giving address as localhost and port is 8080. I am using `Jmeter 2.11.`
I am under corporate proxy.

Please suggest to resolve this error.

Thanks In Advance,
Kane

Answer (score 3):

If you're under a corporate proxy you need to start JMeter a little bit differently:

Proxy-related command-line arguments are:

> ```
>     -H, --proxyHost <argument>
>             Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
>     -P, --proxyPort <argument>
>             Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
>     -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
>             Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>     -u, --username <argument>
>             Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -a, --password <argument>
>             Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
> ```

So if you launch JMeter as follows:

```
jmeter -H your_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port etc
```

you should be able to record applications requiring Internet access via corporate proxy

See [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) guide for more details and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Add your corporate proxy address in the HTTP Request window
(which is located at bottom of window)